# Curvilinear Coordinate with coordinate curves that look like cosine in 2D

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis, curvilinear-coordinates

There are curvilinear coordinates with coordinate curves that look like rays and circles, i.e. polar coordinates, and there are curvilinear coordinates with coordinate curves that look like parabolas, i.e. parabolic coordinates. Can we write down a curvilinear coordinate with one coordinate curve that looks cosine and another coordinate curve being orthogonal to it? Specifically, given a family of curves $$x = -\cos(y)+c,$$ with real number $c$ parametrizing this family of curves, can we find another family curves orthogonal to it and together form a curvilinear coordinate? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the parameter being toggled?

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate more on what you mean by parameter being toggled? I'm looking for some basis vector $(g_1, g_2)$ that relates to cartesian basis $(e_x, e_y)$ via some functions $g_1 = f_1(e_x, e_y), g_2 = f_2(e_x, e_y)$ such that the one of the coordinate curve in the new coordinate looks like the cosine curve described above.

Comment: How do you mean "orthogonal function to another"? In with scalar product?

Comment: In the naive sense that the two coordinate curves are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: In your example with "rays and circles", you have a [family of curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_curves), e.g. the rays, and then your are looking for another family of curves orthogonal to it, e.g. the circles. But you have given us only a single curve, not a family. What are we supposed to do with a single curve?

Comment: I have updated the question to include family of curves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your family of curves

$$x+\cos y = c$$

implicitly differentiate both sides

$$1 - \sin y \frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sin y}$$

then take the negative reciprocal of the quantity to find a new differential equation to solve

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\sin y \implies |\sin y| =  \operatorname{sech}(x+c)$$

With a little tweaking we find the precise family

$$x + c = \operatorname{sgn}(\cos y)\operatorname{arsech}|\sin y|$$

This is your orthogonal family of curves.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to find two parameters that can parameterize these two families of curves? Similar to how in polar coordinates we use $(r,\theta)$ to parametrize and can write $x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta)$, is there a way to find two parameters in this case?

Comment: @Sean how about you try it? Why was it that I and other commenters asked you for a parameter to toggle?

Comment: @Sean, I do not think that this can be done with elementary functions. You have one family of curves $x+\cos y=c_1$ that depends on one parameter $c_1$ and another family of curves $x+c_2 = \mathrm{sgn}(\cos y)\mathrm{arsech}|\sin y|$ that depend on another parameter $c_2.$ You would get your parameterization by fixing $c_1$ and $c_2$ and trying to solve the system of $2$ equations for $x$ and $y$. You would get formalea for $x$ and $y$ that depend on $c_1$ and $c_2$, then. But as I mentioned, this is not possible with elementary functions.